# WPF: Does Microsoft provide XAML source code for standard controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, user-controls, wpf-controls

For this question, it would be helpful if you download these two images:

DataGrid in Main TabItem:

[image]

Very Similar DataGrid in Secondary TabItem:

[image]

If you switch them rapidly with the Windows Viewer, you will notice some subtle differences:

(a) The background color

(b) The margins

Since my objective is to make those `TabItems` almost identical (minus a couple extra fields in the 2nd one), I am told that all I need to do is modify the value some border and/or margin (??).

I wouldn't know where to start implementing that advice. All I need is a `TabControl` with the two lower tabs; they should have 3 sides with the upper being borderless, joining the upper region. Nothing else. No trembling, no shaking upon switching.

How would I go about that? Please be specific.

Does Microsoft provide XAML source code for standard controls?

TIA.

Comment: Yes, the default ControlTemplates can be obtained, however you don't need any of that. There is an issue with `your` XAML. Post your current XAML (do not include `DataGridColumn`s or things like that. this is a layout issue).

Comment: Otherwise inspect the running application at runtime with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to find out what differences there are in these 2 Views.

Comment: Can't you just compare the XAML of the two files? In Visual Studio, you can right click on the tab that contains the filename of each class and select either 'New Horizontal Tab Group' or 'New Vertical Tab Group' to view two files side by side.

Comment: @Sheridan why do you always come up with a better solution than mine? :P

Comment: I indeed *did* have some differences, in XAML as well as CodeBehind. Since then, I decided that one is always copy&pasted from the other. @HighCore, the lowering/shifting of secondary tabs is a *feature*. It is supposed to provide the visual impression of switching, one which I would prefer to eliminate in this particular app.

Comment: @TravisBanger I already told you that if there are very few or minor differences between these two, don't copypaste them. Use a single View (UserControl) and toggle the visibility of it's contents as needed.

Comment: "Can't you just compare the XAML of the two files?" I have done that. After being the victim of such trouble, I only make my changes in the primary tab and then I copy&paste the full file to the secondary. Finally, I rename a few lines from "72" to "48".

Comment: @TravisBanger there is no such thing as a `secondary tab` in WPF. In WPF, items in an `ItemsControl` are treated all equal, unless there is a `user-defined` mechanism that does otherwise.

Comment: I don't know about that @HighCore... using a single view is a pretty good idea. ;)

Comment: "don't copypaste them. Use a single View (UserControl) and toggle the visibility". That wise advice is in my (long) "List of Things to Do". I had no idea that there was such a thing as View until you mentioned it a few days ago.

Comment: " there is no such thing as a secondary tab in WPF." I claim that visually there is. Just to satisfy myself, I will create one TabControl alone, with 2 TabItems and switch them. The GUI designers must be upset when they read what you wrote. Without that shift, we would not notice the action. I insist that it is there to provide **visual feedback**, which is essential in GUIs.

Comment: In WPF, View == UserControl | Window

Comment: @TravisBanger `Without that shift, we would not notice the action` - only in your case, where the 2 tabs contain the same :S if "tab1" has a completely different UI than "tab2" then there is no additional "visual feedback" required.

Comment: "Without that shift, we would not notice the action." Having said that, I have no idea how they provide a visual cue when switching from TabItem2 to TabItem3 or 4, etc.

Comment: @TravisBanger again, a `TabControl` is intended to have **completely different** UIs on each tab. I guess we're back into the discussion of whether a `RadioButton` makes more sense in your case.

Comment: Okay, guys... I will go experiment with 1 TabControl, 2 or more TabItems...

Comment: @HighCore: "TabControl is intended to have completely different UIs on each tab." The `Excel` designers beg to differ. :-)

Comment: @TravisBanger in excel, switching tabs in an empty file does not have any visual feedback, except for the highlighting of the selected tab `Header`.

Comment: @HighCore: Maybe you are right. I have been experimenting with a very simplistic `TabControl` with 2 `DataGrids` inside and I cannot detect any visual switching. In any event, this goes to the bottom of my priorities.

Comment: @HighCore: "Yes, the default ControlTemplates can be obtained" Just out of curiosity, and for future use: Where? How? For free?

Comment: @TravisBanger [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @HighCore: I posted that MSDN page. The problem is that my users are engineers and not Japanese teenage girls, fans of "Hello Kitty" :-) :-) I tried those examples and they are **purple**, very different from the corporate, production controls that we use on a daily basis.

Comment: Like I said, this artsy stuff is too much work. I will postpone it, have other crucial skills to learn...

Comment: @TravisBanger that depends on the selected Windows Theme, those are probably from `PresentationFramework.Luna` or the like. What I do when I need to get a hold of the default WPF Templates is to [Use Expression Blend](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/using-blend-to-find-default-style-xaml/) to extract them to XAML.

Comment: Guys: FWIW, you are correct. It turns out that the screenshots I posted in this question are ancient (from 2 days ago :-). Now I am using copy+paste and the 2 `TabIems` show no variation whatsoever upon switching.

Comment: @TravisBanger, any chance of you deleting this 'question' now that it is no longer relevant and seeing that its title is somewhat misleading? It's of no help to any other users.